# Unable to retrieve the item from cosmos db container

Tags: python, azure-cosmosdb

It is not able to retrieve the item from container using item_id and partition_key.

Here is code snippet

```py
from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient, PartitionKey

cosmos_client = CosmosClient(url=cosmos_endpoint, credential=cosmos_key)
database = cosmos_client.create_database_if_not_exists(id="database")
container = database.create_container_if_not_exists(id="container", partition_key=PartitionKey(path="/partition"))

container.create_item(body={"id": "id-1"})
container.read_item(item="id-1", partition_key="/partition")
```

response from api:

```bash
 ResourceType: Collection, OperationType: Read
, SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0
Code: NotFound
Message: Message: {"Errors":["Resource Not Found. Learn more: https:\/\/aka.ms\/cosmosdb-tsg-not-found"]}
```

I tried with different values for partition_key, for instance,

```py
container.read_item(item="id-1", partition_key=PartitionKey(path="/partition"))
```

which gave error of bad request.

```py
container.read_item(item="id-1", partition_key="id-1")
```

which is not able retrieve the item.

Here is information I gathered for container from database client:

```
>>>database.list_containers().next()
{'_conflicts': 'conflicts/',
 '_docs': 'docs/',
 '_etag': '"0000fb09-0000-0c00-0000-647453610000"',
 '_rid': 'zOBqAK0Az6I=',
 '_self': 'dbs/zOBqAA==/colls/zOBqAK0Az6I=/',
 '_sprocs': 'sprocs/',
 '_triggers': 'triggers/',
 '_ts': 1685345121,
 '_udfs': 'udfs/',
 'conflictResolutionPolicy': {'conflictResolutionPath': '/_ts',
                              'conflictResolutionProcedure': '',
                              'mode': 'LastWriterWins'},
 'geospatialConfig': {'type': 'Geography'},
 'id': 'container',
 'indexingPolicy': {'automatic': True,
                    'excludedPaths': [{'path': '/"_etag"/?'}],
                    'includedPaths': [{'path': '/*'}],
                    'indexingMode': 'consistent'},
 'partitionKey': {'kind': 'Hash', 'paths': ['/partition'], 'version': 2}}
```

Comment: You need to specify the value of the partition key here `container.read_item(item="id-1", partition_key="/partition")` instead of the path.

Comment: Yup - for `partition_key` you need to set it to `"id-1"` - the same value you used in your `create_item()` call in your example. This is a fairly common mistake...

Comment: @GauravMantri, I tried the same, in the description but failed to retrieve the exact item.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, I tried with container.read_item(item="id-1", partition_key="id-1"), but still not able to retrieve the item. Can you share more ideas?

Comment: What’s the partition key value of the document?

Comment: Please edit to update, vs posting details in comments.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, I have updated in the post. :-)

Comment: @GauravMantri, I added the properties for the container from the database. The partition_key value is supposed to be "/partition" based on my understanding.

Comment: Looks like you’re not explicitly setting the partition key for the document at the time of creation.  Please note that you must set a partition key value when creating a document.

Comment: @GauravMantri You are right. I need to specify the partition_key given the created one. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not explicitly setting the partition key value when you are creating the document. If that happens, Cosmos DB automatically puts the documents in a special partition.

Because point read queries require both document id and partition key, when reading such documents you would need to specify partition key as an empty javascript object (`{}`).

Please try something like:

```
container.read_item(item="id-1", partition_key={})
```

Generally speaking, you must explicitly set the partition key value in creating the document. For example, if you had done something like:

```
container.create_item(body={"id": "id-1", "partition": "id-1"})
```

You could have read the same document using your code:

```
container.read_item(item="id-1", partition_key="id-1")
```